# Edit file name in entity with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, upload, doctrine, symfony-3.4

Hello *(excuse my English, not too confident with it)*

I'm actually working on a Symfony website that display some spectacles' information.
For now, I need to add an image when I create one of them. I managed to do so with the help of **[this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html)** tutorial.

It basically works like this: I upload an image into site's directory and then send file's name to the entity *(Store in a MySQL database)*. I can then display the image in spectacle's details.

The issue appeared when I want to edit a spectacle. I can't update the image's  name. I have two only possibilities are to 1/not edit the entity, or to 2/change the image name and then get a random one that I can't display anymore *(these names are usually like **/tmp/phpWb8kwV**)*

My image is instantiate like this in the entity *(in Spectacle.php)*:

```
/**
* @var string
*
* @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
* @Assert\NotBlank(message="Veuillez ajouter une image à votre spectacle.")
* @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/png" })
*/
private $image;
```

And the FormType for the spectacle's form is made like this *(in SpectacleType.php)*:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nom')
            ->add('lieu')
            ->add('dateSpectacle', null, array(
                'label' => 'Date du spectacle',
            ))
            ->add('annee')
            ->add('image',FileType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Image du spectacle',
                'required' => false, //(Still need to provide a file to finalize the creation/edit)
            ));
}
```

And the controller to acces this page is made like this *(in SpectacleController.php)*:

```
/**
 * Creates a new spectacle entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="admin_spectacle_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $spectacle = new Spectacle();
    $form = $this->createForm('FabopBundle\Form\SpectacleType', $spectacle);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
        $file = $spectacle->getImage();            
        $fileName = (md5(uniqid())).'.'.$file->guessExtension();            
        // moves the file to the directory where image are stored
        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('img_directory'), //(Define in the service.yml)
            $fileName
        );
        $spectacle->setImage($fileName); //(Don't know how to handle file names without this line)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
        $em->persist($spectacle);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_spectacle_show', array('id' => $spectacle->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('spectacle/new.html.twig', array(
        'spectacle' => $spectacle,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The function that is routed to the edit view is approximatively the same, but i can't use

```
$spectacle->setImage($fileName);
```

---

There is two possibilities to solve this: I would like being able to update the new filename in the entity (with the other information) or being able to update the entity without changing filename.

I hope I was clear enough to explain my problem... 
Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was stupid ...

In fact, the controller to access the *edit* route didn't have those lines:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
...
$em->persist($spectacle);
$em->flush();
```

> I need to finish this quickly. If i have more time later, i'll try to make it work with the ComurImageBundle.

Thank you for your help, i'll be more carefull next time ...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when trying to upload a PDF/TEXT.. file.
But for managing images, I advice you to use ComurImageBundle, it helps you a lot and your problem will be resolved.
It's very simple, you download the bundle like it's explained in this [link](https://github.com/comur/ComurImageBundle).
Then you modify your code like this :
**1/** Instantiation of your image in Spectacle.php (your image is stored in the DB like string)

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $image;
```

**2/** Update your base ( php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force)

**3/** Add these functions to your Spectacle.php after updating your DB schema, these functions let you upload and stock your images under specific directory (web/uploads/spectacles) and don't forget to add this two libraries

> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
>
> use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

```
  /**
 * @Assert\File()
 */
private $file;

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->image = uniqid() . '.' . $this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    // If there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image);
}

public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'uploads/spectacles';
}

public function getBaseUrl()
{
    $currentPath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $pathInfo = pathinfo($currentPath);

    return substr($pathInfo['dirname']."/", 1);
}

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return $this->getBaseUrl() . $this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->image;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->image;
}
```

**4/** Modify the FormType (SpectacleType.php)like this

```
use Comur\ImageBundle\Form\Type\CroppableImageType;

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nom')
            ->add('lieu')
            ->add('dateSpectacle', null, array(
                'label' => 'Date du spectacle',
            ))
            ->add('annee')
            ->add('image', CroppableImageType::class, array('label' => 'Image', 'required' => true,
            'uploadConfig' => array(
                'uploadUrl' => $myEntity->getUploadDir(),       // required - see explanation below (you can also put just a dir path)
                'webDir' => $myEntity->getUploadRootDir(),              // required - see explanation below (you can also put just a dir path)
                'fileExt' => '*.png',  // required - see explanation below (you can also put just a dir path)
                'showLibrary' => false,
            ),
            'cropConfig' => array(
                'minWidth' => 128,
                'minHeight' => 128,
                'aspectRatio' => true,
            )
        ));    
}
```

**5/** Remove all these lines from your controller you won't need them

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
        $file = $spectacle->getImage();            
        $fileName = (md5(uniqid())).'.'.$file->guessExtension();            
        // moves the file to the directory where image are stored
        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('img_directory'), //(Define in the service.yml)
            $fileName
        );
        $spectacle->setImage($fileName); //(Don't know how to handle file names without this line)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**6/** That's it you can call the form of your image in new.html.twig and edit.html.twig, all will get well, try it please and notify me if there is any problem.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'll try it right now.
I'll add a comment when it's done.

Comment: Finally. After 24h, i've managed to import and configure everything. It seems to be working since the image slot and the "select file" button or displayed. But i get the error: $('#image_upload_file').fileupload is not a function
Do you know where it could came from ?

Comment: I think the problem is coming form JS calls, take a look on my answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49536246/4815698